# Some Galaxy devices failing at shader usage?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a shader for my Android application that blurs objects. It runs fine on all of my devices as well as the great majority of users' devices.

However, a common theme is a crash with Android 4.4.2 **only** with Galaxy Tab 3, Galaxy S duos 2, and some other Galaxy devices (I have a Galaxy Tab 4, and it works fine).

I'm using LibGDX, and the only error report I'm getting is:

```
Thread: GLThread 110, Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_projTrans' in shader
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:308)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:298) 
at...
```

The uniform `u_projTrans` is one LibGDX internally looks for in all shaders to pass in the projection matrix, and I can confirm it is there in the vertex shader just like my other shaders that work on all devices (including the Galaxy ones).

---

I'm assuming this is a generic "fallback" crash description because something else is going wrong with this one specific shader on these devices.

**Trying to not have to go out and buy a used device for testing, maybe someone can have an idea why this shader is causing issues on only a select few 4.4.2 Galaxy devices?**

**Horizontal-blur Vertex**

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform float u_blurPixels;
uniform float u_texelSize;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords[8];
varying vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color =  a_color;
    v_color.a = v_color.a * (255.0 / 254.0);
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;

    float blurDistance3 = u_blurPixels * u_texelSize;
    float blurDistance2 = blurDistance3 * 0.75;
    float blurDistance1 = blurDistance3 * 0.5;
    float blurDistance0 = blurDistance3 * 0.25;

    v_blurTexCoords[ 0] = v_texCoord + vec2(-blurDistance0, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 1] = v_texCoord + vec2( blurDistance0, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 2] = v_texCoord + vec2(-blurDistance1, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 3] = v_texCoord + vec2( blurDistance1, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 4] = v_texCoord + vec2(-blurDistance2, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 5] = v_texCoord + vec2( blurDistance2, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 6] = v_texCoord + vec2(-blurDistance3, 0.0);
    v_blurTexCoords[ 7] = v_texCoord + vec2( blurDistance3, 0.0);
}
```

**Blur Frag**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_blurTexCoords[8];
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
    vec4 summedColor = vec4(0.0);
    float overallAlpha = 0.0;
    int i = 0;
    vec4 fetchedColor;
    float scaleWithAlpha;

    // 0

    fetchedColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    scaleWithAlpha = fetchedColor.a * 0.2204;
    summedColor += fetchedColor * scaleWithAlpha;
    overallAlpha += scaleWithAlpha;

    // 1

    fetchedColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_blurTexCoords[i++]);
    scaleWithAlpha = fetchedColor.a * 0.19;
    summedColor += fetchedColor * scaleWithAlpha;
    overallAlpha += scaleWithAlpha;

    fetchedColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_blurTexCoords[i++]);
    scaleWithAlpha = fetchedColor.a * 0.19;
    summedColor += fetchedColor * scaleWithAlpha;
    overallAlpha += scaleWithAlpha;

    // etc

    summedColor /= overallAlpha;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(summedColor.xyz, overallAlpha * v_color.a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the program failed to link because you have exceeded GL_MAX_VARYING_VECTORS for the implementations in question. The errors you're seeing have probably cascaded from this problem. OpenGLES 2 allows implementations to have a max varying count as low as 8. See table 6.20 of the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf).

According to [gpuinfo.org's database](http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/gles_generatereport.php?reportID=246) the Galaxy S duos 2 appears to have 8 varyings. There are lots of different variants of the Galaxy Tab 3, so I couldn't really conclude anything about that.

You should be able to work around easily by squeezing the 10 current varyings you're using (8xv_blurTexCoords, 1xv_texCoord, 1xv_color) into 8 slots by packing some of the v_blurTexCoords into vec4s. I recommend doing the minimum amount of packing required to reach 8 varyings, because on some devices packing UVs has a performance impact (read up on 'dependent texture reads' if you want details).

Comment: wow, that would be the issue then, hadn't had a clue about varying limits, especially such a low number, I'm going to implement this and hoping users will report it's all good, thanks!